# UIPageViewController with dynamic DataSource pages gets repeated

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

When I do fast swipe between pages sometimes I get duplicate pages. My index counting may be wrong, but I tried everything and always get the same.

**DetailedProfileViewController.swift**

```
class DetailedProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var currentProfileIndex : Int?
    var nextProfileIndex :Int?
    var data: Main?

    var mainPageView : UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        profile.profile = currentProfile()
        let arraysOfViews = [profile]

        mainPageView = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: [:])
        mainPageView.setViewControllers(arraysOfViews, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        mainPageView.dataSource = self
        mainPageView.delegate = self

        addChildViewController(mainPageView)
        view.addSubview(mainPageView.view)
        mainPageView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if currentProfileIndex == (data?.filteredProfiles.count)!-1 { return nil }
        nextProfileIndex = abs((currentProfileIndex! + 1) % (data?.filteredProfiles.count)!)
        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        profile.profile = data?.filteredProfiles[nextProfileIndex!]
        return profile
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if currentProfileIndex == 0 { return nil }
        nextProfileIndex = abs((currentProfileIndex! - 1) % (data?.filteredProfiles.count)!)
        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        profile.profile = data?.filteredProfiles[nextProfileIndex!]
        return profile
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed == true {
          currentProfileIndex = nextProfileIndex
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not setting all of View Controllers in viewDidLoad because it could be hundreds of them..

Comment: https://github.com/maheshmobile/DynamicHeightPageViewController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dumbest solution is to add an `index` to `ProfileViewController`. If you do so, you can set it as zero to the first page. And whenever you are asked to provide the next or previous view controller, you always know relatively to what index, because you may extract it from the given `pageViewController` (which is in fact your `ProfileViewController`).

Otherwise the handling of the `currentProfileIndex` may be very error-prone.

**UPDATE**

```
class DetailedProfileViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var data: Main?

    var mainPageView : UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        profile.index = 0
        profile.profile = currentProfile()
        let arraysOfViews = [profile]

        mainPageView = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: [:])
        mainPageView.setViewControllers(arraysOfViews, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        mainPageView.dataSource = self
        mainPageView.delegate = self

        addChildViewController(mainPageView)
        view.addSubview(mainPageView.view)
        mainPageView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let pagesCount = data?.filteredProfiles.count else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let newIndex = (viewController as? ProfileViewController).index + 1, newIndex < pagesCount else {
            return nil
        }

        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        profile.profile = data?.filteredProfiles[newIndex]
        profile.index = newIndex
        return profile
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let pagesCount = data?.filteredProfiles.count else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let newIndex = (viewController as? ProfileViewController).index - 1, newIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil
        }


        let profile = ProfileViewController()
        profile.profile = data?.filteredProfiles[newIndex!]
        profile.index = newIndex
        return profile
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting it. I would set profile.index = 0 the first time, and what would I do in Before and After?

Comment: In before and after, you also have `pageViewController: UIPageViewController` as a param. For example, if it's 10, then when you create a before view controller it should be 9, after – 11.

Comment: Sometring like let profile = pageViewController as? ProfoileViewController? I can't really do so?

Comment: I get this error: Cast from 'UIPageViewController' to unrelated type 'ProfileViewController' always fails. :/

Comment: You're right! `viewController` has to be casted to `ProfileViewController` in both methods. I've fixed the answer. Please, try again.

Comment: https://github.com/maheshmobile/DynamicHeightPageViewController